# Multiply variable number of arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Say I have a variable amount of arguments which I want to multiply together. The first way I think of is a recursive algorithm:

```
template<typename Head>
u64 Multiply(Head head) const
{
    return head;
}

template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
u64 Multiply(Head head, Tail... tail) const
{
    return head * Multiply(tail...);
}
```

But then I saw this trick:

```
// u32 and u64 are 32 and 64 bit unsigned integers.
template<typename... T>
u64 Multiply(T... args)
{
    u64 res = 1;
    for (const u32& arg: {args...})
        res *= arg;
    return res;
}
```

The second one appears way nicer to me. Easier to read. However, how does this act on performance? Is anything being copied? What does `{args...}`  do in the first place? Is there a better method?

I have access to C++14.

**Edit to be clear: It is about run time multiplication, not compile time.**

**More to be clear: I do not want to compute integers necessarily(although that is my current application), but the algorithm that I found was specialized for integers.**

**More: Arguments are of the same type. Algorithms without this restriction would be very interesting but maybe for a different question.**

Comment: I think, the second approach might not work when values of *mixed* integral types passed to the function, like : `Multiply(1, 1u, 1ul, 1ull);`.

Comment: The second function assumes that `T` is of integral type, which is not the case for the first function

Comment: @Snps Why should #1 be at compile time? It is run time, just like #2

Comment: @Rakete1111 Hmm, I think you're right. I take it back!

Comment: Or wait for C++17 and `return (args * ... * 1);`.

Comment: Your loop is uses `u32` explicitly.  Are all the arguments required to be `u32`?

Comment: @KerrekSB Why not just `return (args * ...);`?

Comment: @Rakete1111: Because it's pointlessly elliptic for no benefit and makes me pause and think for longer than I care to :-S

Comment: @Rakete1111: is `return (args * ...);` valid C++14?

Comment: @VaughnCato Arguments are not necessarily integers. See my edit. If integers would make the algorithm less complex, I would find that interesting too.

Comment: @KerrekSB I do not have access to C++17. Maybe in a few years.

Comment: Are all the arguments necessarily of the same type?  That will be required if using `{args...}`.

Comment: @Klaus No, it is C++17

Comment: Try to compare the assembly produced by the code e.g. in godbolt: [example](https://godbolt.org/g/2LpShz). In my opinion when you use -O2 compiler may introduce optimizations that won't require additional structure, but I admit I didn't go through entire assembly too deeply...

Comment: @VaughnCato Yes arguments are of the same type.

Comment: In response to your 2nd example, following your elaborations: Why not just pass an `std::initializer_list` (or even `vector`) to the function directly, rather than wastefully generating a near-duplicate instantiation of the function for each possible number of arguments and then having it pack them into an `initializer_list` _anyway_...? Using a parameter pack here seems very wasteful and (in light of your clarifications) for no conceivable benefit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple questions asked here:

1. What's the impact on performance? Dunno. You'll need to measure. Depending on the type of the arguments I can imagine that the compiler entirely optimizes things either way, though: it does know the number of arguments and the types.
2. What is `{ args... }`? Well, it creates an `std::initializer_list<T>` for the common type of the arguments (assuming there is one). You may want to use the value with `std::common_type_t<T...>` instead of a fixed type, though.
3. Is there a better method? There are a couple of approaches although I could imagine that the compiler actually does rather well with this expansion. The alternative which immediately comes to mind is `return (args * ... * 1);` which, however, requires C++17. If there is at least one argument the `* 1` can be omitted: it is there to avoid a compile-time error if there is an empty list of variadic parameters.

Comment: There is no compile error when the parameter pack is empty, please see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4295.html. It also defaults to 1, so `* 1` is unnecessary

Comment: @Rakete1111 [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) states something quite opposite... not sure though which is right

Comment: @W.F. Maybe the proposal was modified by the committee before being accepted, and no updated paper was published to reflect the change?

Comment: @Rakete1111: I do know that they messed with the default in case there is an empty parameter pack. I didn't pay much attention to the discussion, though. There is, e.g., [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0036r0.pdf).

Comment: If I understand correctly, creating an initializer list using this method copies the arguments? Compiler optimizations aside.

Comment: @AartStuurman: yes, the elements in the `std::initializer_list` are copied. If the compiler can't tell that the copy constructor and destructor don't have side-effects it actually definitely has to copy them. For built-in types I would expect that all that behavior is removed, though.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Wut? The standard allows elision of copy-constructions even when they do have side-effects. Isn't that the defining feature of copy elision?

Comment: @underscore_d: the rules for copy-elision are defined in 12.8 [class.copy] paragrapgh 32 (reference from memory but shoukd be close). They are [deliberately] fairly specific. I don't recall copy elision being allowed when constructing members of another object. While `std::initializer_list<T>` is conceptually just a pointer to the begin/end of a sequence of values I think there is an implicit assumption that this range is actually built.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration. It appears to me the first algorithm has the highest chance of being the most efficient, as it is very obvious what to inline. Looking forward to using C++17 fold.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
template<typename... T>
u64 Multiply(T... args)
{
    u64 res = 1;
    for (const u32& size : {args...})
        res *= size;
    return res;
}
```

is a bit mysterious to me :-) Why we have template parameters with type T and inside the method we used fix size values? And the variable name `size` looks very obscure because this var has nothing to do with any kind of size. And using integer types inside is also not a valid assumption if you give floating point data into the template.

OK, but to answer your question:

The first one can be used with all types you put into the template function. The second one used fixed ( unsigned integer ) types, which is not what I expect if I see the declaration of the template itself.

Both version can be made `constexpr` as I learned now :-) and work pretty well for compile time calculation.

To answer the question from your comment:

```
{args...}
```

expands to:

```
{ 1,2,3,4}
```

which is simply an "array" ( std::std::initializer_list)  and only works if all elements have the same type.

So having

```
for (const u32& size : {args...})
```

simply iterates over the array.

Comment: "You recursive example would do the job during compile-time!" Nope, it would not do the job at compile time, it might be optimized if the compiler is clever, or not.

Comment: You actually can make the second one run at compile time, if you make it `constexpr` :)

Comment: @Rakete1111: Yes, relaxed constexpr rules... I will change my post :-) Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but this was not completely what I was looking for. I know what both functions are used for, but what I don't understand it how the second one performs and how {args...} works. About the size variable name, that was a leftover of some tests I did with it :)